# jQuery audio fade out and pause, onclick fade in audio and resume

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

What is the problem here? When I click the `#background_audio div`, the audio fades out then automatically fades in and continues playing without me pressing the button again. How do I fix it?

I am trying to make it so that the audio fades out and pauses when #background_audio is clicked, and then when `#background_audio` is clicked again, the audio fades in and resumes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mute').click(function(){
        $('#background_audio').animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){('#background_audio').pause()},1000);
    });
    $('#mute').click(function(){
        $('#background_audio').animate({volume: 1}, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){('#background_audio').pause()},1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are adding two click handlers to same jQuery element, so on a single click two handlers will be called.

You have to add an `if` that verify if the sound was muted.

When you will click on the button the sound will be muted or un-muted with fadeIn.

### HTML

```
<div style="bottom:0; position:absolute; height:32px; width:100%;">
    <button id="mute">Mute sound</button>
    <audio id="background_audio"  src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/2541.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var backAudio = $('#background_audio');

    var muted = false;

    $('#mute').click(function(){
        var button = $(this);
        if (!muted) {
            button.attr("disabled", "");
            backAudio.animate({volume: 0}, 1000, function () {
                muted = true;
                button.removeAttr("disabled", "");
                button.text("Unmute sound");
            });
        }
        else {
            button.attr("disabled", "");
            backAudio.animate({volume: 1}, 1000, function () {
                muted = false;
                button.removeAttr("disabled", "");
                button.text("Mute sound");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/X4cu9/1/)

Comment: I don't use an audio plugin. I tried the code you provided, and it only faded the audio out once the #background_audio div was clicked, but when it was clicked again, the audio did not fade back in and resume playing.

Comment: Are you sure that you've updated the script into page? Clear the cache, please.

Comment: Yes I am sure (otherwise your code wouldn't have behaved differently than mine).

Comment: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/X4cu9/

For some reason, jsfiddle isn't closing the <audio> and <div> tags properly... so it's not even muting the audio the way it does when I test it on my server with your code.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I would up vote the answer, but it says I need at least 15 reputation.

Comment: @viksra Thanks, but all your votes were reset. But keep [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/john?tab=answers&sort=newest) in your attention and vote max 5 votes/day. :-) Thanks!